# Как обновить день и месяц следующего понедельника в определенное время?

Tags: javascript

Для вывода дня и месяца следующего понедельника используется код:

```
var d = new Date();
var monthNames = new Array("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь");

d.setDate(d.getDate() + (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);
var date = d.getDate() + ' - ' + monthNames[d.getMonth()];
```

Например, при заходе на страницу 10 или 13 февраля в переменной date будет "13 - Февраль". Если зайти 14 февраля, то в переменной date будет "20 - Февраль". Как вывести дату нового понедельника не во вторник, а в понедельник после 19 часов?

Проблема в том, что setDate принимает число от 1 до 31. И не понятно, как передать 19 часов.